# UI Stack when adding many document to firestore in one time

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have object "Hour" in my project

That is my function to add hour to firestore.

```
func addHour(_ hour: Hour) {
        
            do {
                let _ = try self.db.collection("hours").addDocument(from: hour)
            } catch {
                fatalError("Unable to uncode hour:")
            }
        
    }
```

It work perfect when adding hour individually but when adding 24 hours in one click it take near 20 second for UI to return interactive

and that is my snapshot listener to load data from firestore and save in repository.

```
init() {
        loadData()
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        let rf = db.collection("hours").order(by:"hourNumber")
            rf.addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
                if let querySnapshot = querySnapshot {
                    self.hours = querySnapshot.documents.compactMap { document in
                        try? document.data(as: Hour.self)
                    }
                }// if let
            }
    }
```

and that is button action that add 24 hour in one click

```
for index in 1...24 {
                        let myHour: Hour = Hour(number: index)
                        self.hourRepository.addHour(myHour)
        }
```

and I tried many method like background thread ...
and delay async it dost work and UI get stacked for 20 seconds

so my question how i can add 24 document to firestore in on click and UI does not stack ..?!

Comment: Update your data in a batched write: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes

Comment: to perform background tasks in firebase on server-side is possible to use firebase functions

Answer (score 0):

You could look at swift 5.5 concurrency,
"Swift has built-in support for writing asynchronous and parallel code in a structured way." see "https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html"
Together with await/async and the SwiftUI task, such as:

```
    .task {
        await loadData()
    }
    
    func loadData() async { ... }
```